# Adding matching labels to a dataframe after filter()

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, apply

how can I match and add the associated strings in a column after using filter()?

```
x<- c("1","2","3","4")  
y<- c("yes","no","maybe","NA")  
df3<-cbind.data.frame(x,y)  
unx<- unique(df3$x)  
x<- c(1:10)  
y<- LETTERS[1:10]  
df4<-cbind.data.frame(x,y )  
all<- df4 %>% filter(x %in% unx)
```

To "all" I would like to add a column with the matching responses in y.

I am out of thoughts, what is the most efficient way of doing it? I would like to apply it to a large dataset. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all$response <- df3$y[match(all$x, df3$x)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was perfect.

Comment: anytime, please consider clicking the check mark (and up vote) indicating that you are satisfied with the answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in *dplyr* a `left_join()` should do the trick.

In your question above, factors sneak in and x is being cast into different types; thus the complete answer would be to begin your script with `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` (unless you choose to take the even better approach and start working with [tibbles.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html))
Then the complete answer would be as below:

```
all <- 
    df4 %>%
    filter(x %in% unx) %>%
    mutate(x = as.character(x)) %>%
    left_join(df3, by = "x")
```